# Unexpected color value from Resources.Theme.resolveAttribute

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TypedValue color = new TypedValue();
    getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorSecondary, color, true);
    Toast.makeText(this, String.format("%x", color.data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This code should make a toast showing the secondary text color. If I put it in one of my older apps, it shows `ffaaaaaa` as expected. If I make a new app, the exact same code shows `a07`. This is obviously wrong; if I try to use it as a color I get invisible views because the first byte (alpha) is 0. What is going on here?

Both apps use:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
```

EDIT:
I tried running the new app on another phone and it shows `aaa`. This is interesting because the color `#aaa` is equivalent to `#ffaaaaaa`. The TypedValue has a `type` field, and on the new app (value=0xaaa) it's TYPE_STRING, but on the old app (value=0xffaaaaaa) it's TYPE_INT_COLOR_RGB4. It seems somehow the newer app is interpreting the value as a string instead of a color. Now I know what's going wrong, but not why or what to do about it.

Comment: You might have a color resource defined elsewhere, It could be grabbing that value instead.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#textColorSecondary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the solution I was hoping for, but if I manually set textColorSecondary in my app's style and make sure to retrieve it with an activity context rather than the application context, it works as expected.

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_secondary</item>
</style>
```